# Server 2012 keeps booting to the blue "Choose an Option" screen

Tags: windows-server-2012

After enabling Hyper-V, my server restarted and now insists on starting to the blue "Choose an Option" page with the options "Continue: Exit and continue to Windows Server 2012 Datacenter" Troubleshoot and Turn off your PC. It seemed obvious to click continue, but when I do, it just restarts the computer and sends me back to this screen. I tried clicking troubleshoot and then going to command prompt just to see if maybe my mbr got dorked up, and when I do it actually asks me to login to get the permissions for the prompt. I login as administrator and I get the prompt, I can see that my drives are all where they're supposed to be. I tried restarting in safe mode, but it did the same thing; it just takes me back to the options screen. Same result when "boot to last known good configuration" Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check your BIOS configuration to see if UEFI is enabled?

Comment: I assume you mean secure boot. I don't seem to have an option to enable or disable it.

Comment: I am assuming you have done bootrec.exe /fixboot and /fixmbr as you have mentioned.. when the pc loads and you press F8, do you see an option to disable restart on system failure?

Comment: I do. I tried that with the same results :/

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is trying to refresh the OS. Try that? You can also just double check the disk with Gparted. The former I suspect may provide better results.

Comment: Refresh only gives me the option to restore a backup of which I have none :(. The disk shows no errors. Man this is frustrating!

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to go to Advanced Tools > Command line and enter: 

ServerManagerCmd.exe -remove Hyper-V -restart

OR

dism /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:Hyper-V (dism /online /disable-feature /? for a full list of features)

Comment: ServerManagerCmd.exe is not present in Server 2012. I'm not able to locate a way to disable features in command line for 2012, but I'm still looking. DISM is saying that it cannot support /Online for windows PE. Even if I leave that option out, it doesn't recognize disable-feature